# Updating state of a Pie chart series on click in Apexchart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

I have setup this example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-basic-example-o9brk?file=/src/App.js

What I want to do is to change my series when I click on a section or legend.

When you try to click any of those, there is a console error: `Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null`

Am I doing anything wrong? Is there another way of doing this?
Thanks for any help or idea you could provide.

Answer (score 0):

After a long investigation of this problem (which I also encountered recently), I found a solution: change the event from "dataPointSelection" to "click"